# Insertion query duplicating records in incremental manner in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, duplicates, insert

I have a simple commenting system that I'm using AJAX to comment and fetch comments. But I have started experiencing duplicated comments for each comment. Here is how it's going on: the first comment is not duplicated, the second comment gets doubled(gets duplicated), the third gets tripled...and so on in that trend. How do I fix that?

```
`//THIS IS THE COMMENTING PHP FILE
<?php
include '../DB-config/db-config.php';

if (!empty($_POST['comment_text']) && !empty($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['page_url'])) {

    $comment = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['comment_text']);
    $user_email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
    $user_id = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
    $page_url = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['page_url']);
    
    
    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id, user_email, page_url, parent_id, comment) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "', '" . $user_email . "','" . $page_url . "', '0', '" . $comment . "')";
    
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, $INSERT);

}
?>`

//AJAX

`$('#comment-post').on('click', function (e) {
                $(document).on('submit', '#comment-writting form', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if ($('#comment-textarea').val() == '') {
                        $('#comment-notice').html('Write a comment...').css('color', 'red');
                        $('#comment-notice').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#comment-notice').hide();
                        var user_email = $('#user_email').val();
                        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
                        var page_url = window.location.search;
                        var comment_text = $('#comment-textarea').val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "../Ajax/comment.php",
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: { user_email: user_email, user_id: user_id, page_url: page_url, comment_text: comment_text },
                            success: function (response) {
                                $('#comment-textarea').empty();
                                $('.emojionearea.emojionearea-inline > .emojionearea-editor').empty();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
            });`
```

Comment: You want to reset the value -- empty resets the child nodes, it doesn't clear out the value. You want `$('#comment-textarea').val('');` instead

Comment: I had tried that before but could not erase the input. Let me add both and see whether it solves the issue

Comment: @aynber it has not fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be having the same problem, I have fixed my problem by using **element.unbind(eventType)** after the event has performed its task

for example in my case: **$('#comment-post').unbind('click');** after Ajax response.